# I want to reverse my extended desktop monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I am using a monitor and a laptop. Currently the desktop appears on the laptop screen and the monitor is the extended desktop. I want it to be the other way around but I can figure out how to do this. Is is possible to configure it so the desktop appears on the monitor and the laptop screen is the extended screen? I am using windows 7 by the way.

Answer (score 7):

There is an option on the settings to set a monitor as your primary. Check that for the monitor. Your taskbar will move to this.

1. Right click desktop and select "Screen Resolution".
2. Click Identify to show numbers on screens.
3. Click the correct screen on the window corresponding to the monitor.
4. Check "Make this my default display" if not checked.

Answer (score 1):

Right click your desktop and select "Screen Resolution".  Select your external monitor (will usually be #2), and click the check box that says "Make this my main display", and press Apply.  That should make your external monitor your primary, and move the taskbar over.